# chrome.fileSystem api file to temp directory

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, html5-filesystem

How can i write file to temp directory in chrome filesystem api?

```
        chrome.fileSystem.getWritableEntry("temp dir here", function(entry) {
            var uniqid = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1)+Date.now();
            entry.getFile(uniqid+'.txt', {create:true}, function(entry) {
                entry.createWriter(function(writer) {
                    writer.write(new Blob([printText], {type: 'text/plain'}));
                });
            });
        });
```

I need this unique `.txt` to write to temp dir and then get that location..

Comment: What do you need it for? To write to the real filesystem you need the user's consent, you can't just pick a location. If you only need a temp file, you can do it with a virtual filesystem.

Comment: How can i do with virtual filesystem? I need to create file in temp folder, then copy to another folder. Complicated, but need it in that way :(

Comment: Question is, do you need it accessible to the user, or only inside the app? (also, I suppose extension tag does not apply, since it's an app-only API)

Comment: My app will create file to temp folder, and then copy it to second(my custom location), and then third-party software will print that to thermal printer, becouse it watch for new files in that second location and prints them. That is point. This is chrome app, not extension.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the HTML5 virtual filesystem as your "staging" location before copying it to the final "real" folder. You'll still need to request access to the final folder.

Most details can be found in [Exploring the FileSystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) article, but the idea is as follows: `chrome.fileSystem` API is built on the same principles, you just get different entries when you request them with `chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry`

To get a virtual filesystem instead of a real one, you need a different call:

```
window.webkitRequestFileSystem(
  window.TEMPORARY,
  5*1024*1024 /* 5MB, adjust as needed, may require "unlimitedStorage" permission */,
  onInitFs,
  errorHandler
);

function onInitFs(filesystem) {
  /* do something with filesystem.root, which is a DirectoryEntry,
     just as you would with `chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry` */
}
```

For more documentation, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_System_API) is a good place.

**Yes, there are big red scary warnings "do not use".** It's not portable since only Chrome implements it and other browsers decided not to do that. But for writing specifically a Chrome App it's fine. If you need assurance that Chrome will continue to support it - well, `chrome.fileSystem` is tightly coupled with it.